# Copy file to external device (Android device) from console

Tags: android, windows, command

I've got file on my PC in directory:

- C:\FILE.XYZ

and I would like to copy it to my Android device plugged into usb into:

- This PC\Android USB Device\Device Memory\Android\

by using Windows console. However command

```
copy "C:\FILE.XYZ" "This PC\Android USB Device\Device Memory\Android\"
```

won't work because system cannot find path. Any idea how to access file from external device?

Comment: Is windows cmd necessary? If possible `adb push LOCAL_PATH REMOTE_PATH` seems to be safer.

Comment: Yes it easy and safe way.